# How do I wait until entire array is pushed to execute a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I am creating a payout API for my site, this one is set up around Monero and I am fetching the values needed to make payments and where to send them from my MongoDB database. I am using Mongoose to do this

I have everything mapped out, it grabs from an array the total net value for that day that needs to be paid out and it grabs from another array the latest wallet entry so it knows where to send the amount to.

The problem arises when I'm trying to structure a new array with this data, pushing this data into it.

Monero intrinsically only allows one transaction to be sent out at a time, locking your leftover balance and the amount sent out until that one transaction has been fully confirmed. The one transaction can be split into multiple transactions but it all has to be sent as "one" big chunk.

So when I send the request to Monero it has to include an array of every wallet and what amount each wallet is receiving.

When I'm pushing to the array I noticed it executes the Transfer Monero function for every time it pushes to the array. How do I make it so the array is pushed completely first with every possible value that meets my if statement (Date is today, paymentStatus is set to false, the amount due is not equal or below 0) before sending that variable over for the Transfer Monero function to use?

I've already tried using return functions, etc. Not sure how to implement async/await or Promises

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var moment = require('moment');
var User = require('../models/user');

var moneroWallet = require('monero-nodejs');
var Wallet = new moneroWallet('127.0.0.1', 18083);



var destinations = []
var xmrnet = []

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://)

  // Fetch IDs

  function getID(){ 
    var cursor = User.find({}, function (err, users) {
    }).cursor();
    return cursor;
    }


  var cursor = getID();
  cursor.on('data', function(name){

    var id = name.id

    // Map all users using IDs

    function getUsers(){ 
    var cursor = User.findById(id, function (err, users) {
    }).cursor();
    return cursor;
    }

var cursor = getUsers();
cursor.on('data', function(user){

    net = user.netHistory.map(element => element)
    order = user.orderHistory.map(element => element)
    userWallets = user.userWallets.map(element => element)


        var today = moment();   
        // date is today? validation
        for (var i = 0; i < net.length; i++){



        netDate = net[i].net_date_time

        netStatus = net[i].paymentStatus

        netUSD = net[i].current_usd_net


        xmrnet = net[i].xmr_net

            for (var j = 0; j < userWallets.length; j++){
            xmrwalletsU = userWallets[j].xmr_wallet

            if(xmrwalletsU !== ''){
                xmrwallet = xmrwalletsU
            }
        }

        var Dateistoday = moment(netDate).isSame(today, 'day');;

        if (Dateistoday === true && xmrnet !== 0 && netStatus === false){


            console.log('its true')



            netid = net[i].id



            var destinationsU = [{amount: xmrnet, address: xmrwallet}]

            destinations.push(destinationsU)

            console.log(destinations)
            // problem is right here with destinations^ it pushes one by one 




          // problem over here as well as wallet.transfer executes one by one by the time it gets to the second, the balance is already locked, unable to send
          Wallet.transfer(destinations).then(function(transfer) {
                console.log(transfer);


                var payouts = {
                    payout_date_time: Date(),
                    payout_usd_amount: netUSD,
                    xmr_wallet: xmrwallet,
                    xmr_txid: transfer.tx_hash,
                }


// add payout to payoutHistory array 
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {"$addToSet": { 'payoutHistory': [payouts]}},
            function(err, user) {
              if(err) { console.log(err) }
              else {
                console.log()
              };
            })

// update paymentStatus of specific net entry to true
            User.updateMany({
                "_id": id,
                "netHistory._id": netid
                }, {
                "$set": {
                    "netHistory.$.paymentStatus": true
                }
                }, function(error, success) {

                })

        })   



        }


    }
})
})
```

Comment: Do you want to make a single transfer call with all destinations or a one by one?

Comment: @cEeNiKc Single transfer call